# Disable Focus of Group Header For ExpandableListActivity in Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am extending SimpleExpandableListActivity and also extended the SimpleExpandableListAdapter. So list shows Group header and its children. Now I wish that GroupHeader should not have the focus and focus should be directly applied to children directly. So is there a way I could achieve this?

I also tried extending getGroupView method but was not able to disable focus of group header.

Thanks, nil

Comment: please share your solution if you are done with it !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the [android:focusable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afocusable) attribute on your group header view to false?

Comment: actually as I am extending ExpandableListActivity and not setting any layout to setcontentview and setting the default android list android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 to the adapter so can't set the android:focusable or not aware of how to do so.

Comment: facing same problem ,